# Launching with Heroku, Custom Domain, Database needed

Tags: python, database, heroku, dns

**What I currently have:**

A bunch of files to run my website based on. I have python/flask files to run all of the backend, with SQL statements incorporated, as well as HTML files to display the web pages I would like to have. It is all very basic right now, such as creating a form where users can enter their email address, and it sends a post request (which would then insert into my database).

**What I am looking to do next:**

After struggling with Amazon's AWS for a solid amount of time, I believe that I want to try my shot with Heroku now. I am looking to launch my currently written files onto Heroku's server, using my custom domain name generated with GoDaddy, and link a database to it that I can "somehow" access. I'm not sure where to start with this, and any help or even a good **tutorial** link would be handy.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a step by step [getting started guide for python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) on the Heroku devcenter.

This guide gives you a sample python app you can deploy, along with details of how to easily provision a postgres database to use with that application.

There is also a general reference for [Heroku Python support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) and a guide to [custom domains for apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).